Use Polyethylene Instead of Conduit PVC?
I need to bury a fairly long run of underground conduit (≈150 - 200') to connect from the utility to my house. At today's prices, the cost just for the conduit is prohibitive. Why not use black polyethylene plumbing pipe?
There are two questions here:

What is the difference between conduit PVC and plumbing PVC?
What is the difference between PVC and polyethylene?

I've read a few websites on the matter. I found no direct comparison between polyethylene and conduit PVC, but there is info on the difference between plumbing PVC and conduit PVC; also there is information on the difference between polyethylene and plumbing PVC:

Plumbing PVC decays in the sunlight.
Plumbing PVC has "small ridges" where it connects and is prone to snagging electrical wires as they are being pulled through the pipe.
Plumbing PVC has thicker walls, ergo slightly smaller inside diameter which could cause conductors to bind when being pulled.
Conduit PVC contains fire retardants; plumbing PVC does not.
PVC is inherently more rigid than is polyethylene. PVC leaches compounds into water over time that are toxic, polyethylene does not. PVC, being more brittle, ruptures under overpressure (so is not suitable for compressed air applications), polyethylene does not.

Here is my response to these concerns:

Not a problem if it's buried.
I don't see why "ridges" or "burrs" cannot be removed with a  reamer or a rasp.
Use the next larger diameter.
Being buried in cool, 40 degree Fahrenheit soil strikes me as fire retardant enough, besides… If there is any way it can catch fire underground, it does not strike me as posing a hazard to any structures.
If polyethylene can be buried underground for 60 years without collapsing from pressure of soil over it, despite having little or no internal pressure, I don’t see why that would change if it contained wires instead of water.

I'd also like to point out that polyethylene comes in 200-foot rolls, so there would be NO JOINTS OR SEAMS for the entire underground run, except at each end, where the polyethylene is connected to the conduit PVC.
So here is my design proposal: If I use all code-compliant PVC conduit above ground and well below ground at the utility end of the connection, and all code-compliant PVC conduit above and well below ground on my house end, what does it matter if 150 feet of completely buried tubing between these two points is polyethylene?
Code is supposed to protect us from hazards, not protect the industry’s bottom line from less expensive alternatives. Can anyone explain what HAZARD(s) exist(s) with my proposed design above?

In general, code is written in blood. In other words, people died. Consider it as hard-earned wisdom. At no point in any code body discussions that I have heard was protecting the industry's bottom line brought up. But for you, specifically, if you don't follow code and your house burns down, your insurance company can walk away since you didn't follow code.

For your job, it might be safe.  But what happens if your neighbour/friend/Joe down the street wants to use it also.  An electrical fire underground might not matter, but a fire inside a house would matter.  Electrical conduit is tested for many things to be safe no matter what happens.  Those tests cost big money.

Welcome to DIY! If you haven't already, please visit the tour. Yes as a class poly has advantages over PVC, and in fact there exist PE tubes listed for use as electric conduit just as there are in PVC. (But none that I know of is listed for both plumbing and electric conduit use.) Unfortunately DIY.se isn't the place for a discussion on whether code requirements are worthwhile or whether a plan to ignore them is reasonable. Your question is likely to be closed unless you edit it to fit the community guidelines.

Tractors have a pipe laying attachment which can bury a pipe at 12" to 18", may be an option compared to digging.

There is such a thing as HDPE conduit, but it's generally only used for specialized applications.  You might be able to snag an offcut of it though...

There are actually two types of PVC conduit for electrical use: Scheduled 80 and Schedule 40. What's the difference? Schedule 80 is thicker, which means that (a) it can stand up to more physical damage, (b) it costs more and (c) the inner diameter is smaller, so in some cases larger conduit is needed for a given set of wires.
Why does this matter? The concern about physical damage is primarily for the above-ground conduit. So it is quite reasonable to use PVC Schedule 80 Conduit (not "regular pipe") for parts of the installation and use less expensive PVC Schedule 40 Conduit (not "regular piper") for the 150 ft. underground run.
With the exception of UV-resistance, all the other concerns are quite real for underground conduit. Unless a conduit is totally full of water (so no source of oxygen), fire concerns are very, very real. Follow the rules.

On reading, this implies that Schedule 80/40 are for electrical use (rather than just being general classifications of PVC).  However, you can get either for a variety of uses, e.g. draining storm water.  Just because something is schedule 80/40 doesn't mean that it is suitable for electrical use.  That needs to be checked separately.  Deleting the words "for electrical use" from the first sentence would at least make it not misleading.  Whether it should also mention that not all PVC is suitable for electrical use is something else.

@mdfst13 I specifically and repeatedly used the word "conduit" as that is the term for electrical rather than plumbing.

Well, there's also schedule 40 and 80 for plumbing PVC pipe!

One big thing about code is "use the item according to instructions".
If the manufacturer says "Use this for ... direct-burial electric conduit ... " then code would probably allow it.
If the manufacturer does not include electrical conduit as a use case, then code will not allow its use as electrical conduit.
(FWIW, my well has its power wires in a separate black plumbing pipe next to the water pipe of the same material. The house passed inspection by the city when we bought it. Maybe well use is a special allowed case.)
